# Table with dependent iterator

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to build a table where the iterator is based off of the ith-1 entry in the table.

In other words, the value at *i* is based on a function with *i-1* as its input.

EXAMPLE: Let's assume we're trying to get a pressure profile for a static column of gas. Since a gas's density changes greatly with pressure changes, we would want to break the static column into, say, 50 sections. So, we set the pressure at the bottom of the column and calculate the pressure at the top of the section (*i+1*) using the formula $\ P_h = \rho g h/g_c$ (hydrostatic equation). The next section's known pressure is at *i+1* and we'd solve for *i+2.*

I've tried For and Table and can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Update: I've figured out how to do it with the For[] construct, but not without the loop.

```
pc = List[4100];
For[i = 1, i < 50, i++,
pc = Append[pc, pc[[i]] - \[Rho]gh/gc]]
```

Comment: Sounds like an application for `NestList` or its relatives. However, before trying to come up with a specific example, I'd prefer to have a more concrete starting point. Can you provide an example of the function used for constructing the table?

Comment: Could you maybe talk about what you're **actually** trying to do so we could be more helpful?

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your formula. We have MathJax available here for writing formulae like $P=P_0 \exp\left(-\frac{Mg}{RT}\right)$; you might wish to use it. You might also consider making the pressure dependence explicit...

Comment: In that case, Verbeia's answer gives you what you want: `NestList[# - \[Rho] g h/gc &, 4100, 50 - 1]`. Though, I prefer `4100 - Range[0, 50 - 1] \[Rho] g h/gc` myself.

Comment: J.M.-- You're awesome. Both methods you show here work brilliantly and are twice as fast as that confounded For[] loop.

Comment: @kalewallace - a good thing to know about Mathematica is that if you are using a `For` loop, you are probably doing it wrong. Get to know `Nest`, `Fold` and `MapThread` - you will be glad you did.

Comment: As a side note: the list of pressures you obtain is incorrect as you assume $\rho$ to be independent of P.

Comment: SCdV, Exactly.  The density is highly pressure dependent.  As an easy example here, I fixed it constant. In practice, there's an entire equation of state calculating compressibility and density at each node.

Comment: @kalewallace If you want to ping someone involved in a comment threat you should use @ and the first couple of letters of the commenter's name. If you don't, they won't get notified of your reaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward use of [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html)

```
NestList[f, x, 3]
```

results in:

```
{x, f[x], f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]]}
```

More complex manipulations use [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), for example:

```
NestList[f[#1, a] &, x, 3]
```

results in:

```
{x, f[x, a], f[f[x, a], a], f[f[f[x, a], a], a]}
```

If you have some other input you need to weave into the function, consider [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html)

```
FoldList[{First[#1] + 1, #2} &, {0, 0}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

which results in:

```
{{0, 0}, {1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}
```