# Fastest way to sum pairwise potentials

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been writing a function to sum a pairwise potential on two lists, i.e. two charged bodies, each containing `N >> 1` and `M >> 1` atoms respectively.

I need to be able to calculate the potential of atom-atom, residue-residue or body-body potential.

In order to do so, I've defined the atom-atom, residue-residue, and body-body potentials as

```
Caa[atom1_,atom2_]:= Coulomb[atom1,atom2];
Crr[res1_,res2_]:= Total[Outer[Caa,res1,res2,1],2]
Cbb[body1_,body2_]:= Total[Outer[Crr,body1,body2,1],2]
```

where

```
body1 = {res11,res12,res13,...}
body2 = {res21,res22,res32,...}

res11 = {atom111,atom112,atom113,...}
res12 = {atom121,atom122,atom123,...}
...
res21 = {atom211,atom212,atom213,...}
res22 = {atom221,atom222,atom223,...}
...

atom111 = {{x111,y111,z111},q111}
atom112 = {{x112,y112,z112},q112}
...
atom211 = {{x211,y211,z211},q211}
atom212 = {{x212,y212,z212},q212}
...
```

i.e, two lists (bodies) of residues, which in turn are lists of atoms, all properly indexed.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to define `Crr`and `Cbb`?

I've tried with loops, `Sum`, `Table`, and a the `Total[Outer[...],2]` definition shown, but all seem to take almost the same (very long) time when doing a `Timing` check.

Needless to say, `Coulomb` is a radial function, i.e., it only depends on the distance between `atom1`and `atom2`, and `atom = {{x,y,z},q}`, where `q` is the charge.

**--EDIT 1--**

```
Coulomb[atom1_,atom2_]:= atom1[[2]] atom2[[2]]/Norm[atom1[[1]]-atom2[[1]]]
```

**--EDIT 2--**

In http://pastebin.com/Yf9TKSDx, you can find a *small* example of `body1` and `body2`.

Here, `body1[[i]]`, will give you the *ith* residue of the first body, `body1[[i,j]]`, the *jth* atom of the *ith* residue of `body1`.

The atom-atom potential is calculated by doing

```
Caa[body1[[i,j]],body2[[k,l]]]
```

the residue-residue potential

```
Crr[body1[[i]],body2[[j]]]
```

and the body-body potential

```
Cbb[body1,body2]
```

hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: The `Outer[]` version is quite fast (almost idiomatic); you should maybe look into making `Coulomb[]` more efficient.

Comment: @J.M.Added definition to question. Is there a fastest way to define it?

Comment: Are you sure about this definition? `Norm[v, p]` is the $p$-norm of the vector `v`. Maybe you wanted `EuclideanDistance[]`?

Comment: @J.M. `Norm` is indeed the wrong function in this context. Moreover, it's used incorrectly as its second argument should be a number, not a vector. It would work if you replaced the comma with a minus, but `EuclideanDistance` is better anyway.

Comment: Also I think the definition `Cbb[...]:= Total[Outer[Cbb,..` is wrong and it should be `Crr` at the _rhs_

Comment: **A tip:** when you ask for help with things like this (fastest, cleanest, etc), strip your domain specific details from the problem. No one cares if it is Coulomb potential or something else. These details only make it harder for people to focus on your problem, which is why even a [tag:list-manipulation] question hasn't received an answer in 7 hrs (usually you get 3-4 in the first hr). Assume some simple 2 argument function `f` that's close enough in time complexity to your `Coulomb`, and use `res = RandomReal[...]` (use a seed). Give us something concrete to objectively measure improvement

Comment: also, you could perhaps give some executable code (ie, code that one can run and time to see if any changes help or not). right now one would have to invent numbers to do that.

Comment: @R.M Specific details were added because the form of `Coulomb[]` was suggested to be important for performance. Why speculate on complexity of `Coulomb` if I can simply post it. I'm a physicist and I think in terms of physics, and it seems unfair to say _no one cares_. I don't care if you don't care.

Comment: @acl I posted a small example of `body1`and `body2`. Due to firewall limitations, I was unable to upload the whole bodies in a text file, but I guess pasting the list several times will give a good testing list.

Comment: @J.M. According to Mathematica help, `Norm[v]` is the same that `EuclideanDistance`. As Sjoerd C. de Vries noted, there was an error in the code.

Comment: @Manuel It's fine to post `Coulomb`'s definition... I was asking you to strip all the body-body, residue-residue details which are only confusing. If you understand it, good for you! But keep in mind that you're seeking help from a Q&A site, where most people might not be physicists like you. I'm certainly not. In such cases, it is helpful if you kept the question solely on the list-manipulation part of it without other details. Moving on, am I right in assuming that your `Caa`, `Crr` and `Cbb` work as you expect (i.e., give you the right answer) and all you want to do now is improve speed?

Comment: @Manuel, your definition for `Coloumb` includes a dot product between the two charges, which I'm pretty sure should just be multiplied.

Comment: I truly would like to know why the question is being voted down. All info is there, the code is working and it has, in sum, being answered. Is it really that bad to speak of _atom-atom_ instead of _list-list_?

Comment: @Manuel I have no idea. You got my +1 (though I had no problem with the domain specific language in the first place, but then again I studied biochemistry and physics:).

Comment: Just so you know, I did not downvote this question although I was vocal about stripping away domain specific language. If you [see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/9060/timeline), you were downvoted on the day you asked the question and before you posted the link to pastebin with some more info. If I were to guess, it was because the initial question was confusing, had typos/errors in the code and the code was not executable. Going by the upvotes on my comment, many people agreed with how I felt. The question maybe ok, but a takeaway message would be that simplicity helps.

Comment: @R.M. It's ok. I just believe that downvoting should be constructive. Providing a reason or, in defect, paying close attention to OP editing would be more helpful. Otherwise, it feels like punishment. Regarding the phrasing, it reminded me the faculty years, where mathematicians complained if a problem was stated in physics terms, even though no physics where needed to solve it. I should've provided a working example, but I wasn't asking people to help in any way outside the scope of the site. Is it wrong to provide some context? Don't know, but I sure feel discouraged to participate again.

Comment: @Manuel We all appreciate context to the question. In fact, I'm happy if I know that some abstract list manipulation problem I helped solve has some real world application. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8700/5) that I answered. I immediately understood the question because it was stated in very simple terms and the drawings conveyed all I wanted. Later, in the comments, the OP explained that it had something to do with pressure profiles in oil reservoirs, which was cool. (continued...)

Comment: On the other hand, see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7251/5) also by the same OP (especially the first version). It is an example of overloading the question with DSL. Both the first comments wanted the OP to have a more concrete question and it wasn't upvoted a lot unlike the previous one (although it wasn't downvoted either). The accepted answer too didn't really answer the actual question, but only provided a hint in the general direction using NestList because they couldn't figure out the details of the pressure profile blah blah...

Comment: There are several more examples lying around on this site that I can point to. It's true, some domain specific language gets understood by most people, especially if accompanied by images (e.g. image processing), but not all. I personally appreciate questions with concrete and simplified code, with the context also as a separate paragraph and I often see that such questions reach out to the general audience much better. I'd urge you to not get disheartened by this incident and continue participating here :)

Comment: @R.M I see what you are saying, and I appreciate your input. In future questions I'll try to be more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `Coloumb` function should be:

```
Coulomb[atom1_,atom2_]:= atom1[[2]] atom2[[2]] / Norm[atom1[[1]] - atom2[[1]]]
```

then the calculation of `Cbb[body1,body2]` takes about 240 ms (on my PC) with your example data.

The best scope for speed-up is probably to compile `Crr`. Here I define a compiled function:

```
Crrcomp = Compile[{{res1x, _Real, 2}, {res1q, _Real, 1}, {res2x, _Real, 2}, {res2q, _Real, 1}},
  Plus @@ Flatten[Outer[Times, res1q, res2q]/
     Map[Sqrt[Dot[#.#]] &, Outer[Plus, res1x, -res2x, 1], {2}]]]
```

and redefine `Crr` to call this compiled function:

```
Crr[res1_, res2_] := Crrcomp[res1[[All, 1]], res1[[All, 2]], res2[[All, 1]], res2[[All, 2]]]
```

With this change, `Cbb[body1,body2]` now takes about 7 ms.

If you are using version 8 and have a suitable C compiler installed, you can add the options `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` to the `Compile` function and this brings the timing down to about 4.5 ms.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need some help understanding the code. In `{res1x,_Real,2},{res1q,_Real,1}`, what does the `1` and `2` stand for?

Comment: J.M. pointed out that `Outer` was as fast as possible, therefore I'm accepting this reply as an answer (along with J.M.'s comment), due to significant speed improvement. Thanks Simon.

Comment: @Manuel, the `1` and `2` are the ranks of the arrays. In this case, `res1x` is a 2D array of reals and `res1q1` is a 1D array of reals.